# c ++ overloaded area function with do while loop

Tags: c++

input

```
R r
8 0
0 9.9
5 -1
3.8 7.2
```

its  giving me these errors

```
main.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
   main.cpp:31:26: warning: ‘radius’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
             } while (radius <= 1);
                      ~~~~~~~^~~~
   main.cpp:40:24: warning: ‘length’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
             while (length <= 1 && width <= 1);
                    ~~~~~~~^~~~
   main.cpp:40:38: warning: ‘width’ may be used uninitialized in this function [-Wmaybe-uninitialized]
             while (length <= 1 && width <= 1);
                                   ~~~~~~^~~~
```

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

// function prototype
double calculateArea(double);
double calculateArea(double, double);

int main()
{
    // variables
    char shape;
    double radius, length, width, area;

    do
    {
        cin >> shape;
    }
    while ( shape != 'c' && shape != 'r');

    if (shape == 'c')
    {
        do
        {
            //input value for radius and validate
        } 
        while (radius <= 1);

        // call calculate area with radius
        area =(calculateArea(radius));
        //output area
        cout << "Area of a circle with radius " << radius << " is " << area << endl;
    }
    else // calculate the area of a rectangle
    { 
        // input values for length and width and validate them
        while (length <= 1 && width <= 1); 
        // call calculate area with length and width
        area = calculateArea(length, width);
        // output area
        cout << "Area of a rectangle with length " << length << " and width " << width << " is " << area << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}

// functions 
double calculateArea(double radius)
{
    double area;
    area = 3.14159 * radius * radius;
    return area;
}

double calculateArea( double length, double width)
{
    double area;
    area = length * width;
    return area;
}
```

Comment: The line `//input value for radius and validate` should be replaced by proper code. Because right now there is no assignement of variable radius so it is totally normal that the compiler complains that this value is uninitialized...

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear: **radius** (on if branch) and **length** and **width** may be used uninitialized (on else branch).

Check what are you parsing from user input.

Comment: Ok and how would i fix that im still new to C++ programming

Comment: You probably want to ask the user for them after know if he wants to calculate a circle or a rectangle, didn't?